# XBAP and Javascript communication in .net 4.5 and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, .net, wpf, html, xbap

I have a webpage build with HTML/Javascript and XBAP in iframe.

I want to have a communication mechanism between HTML/Javascript parent page and Xbap.

What ever links I have searched recommend me to go for WPF/E(Silverlight) but most of them are old post(2006/2007). Its been a while since then and hope there must be some mechanism for this with .net 4.5 and HTML5 taking center stage.

PS: Looking for solution better then browser cookies