# Interact with an XBAP application via VBA

Tags: excel, xbap, vba

I work for a service request fulfillment team. We have a XBAP tool that runs an application where we do user rights maangement. For each request, I have to search the user in the XBAP application and then do the needful operations. Is there a way we can interact with the XBAP Application from outside the XBAP framework, like VBA and send commands. I'm looking forward to design a solution in Excel using VBA that can loop through the requests. That is the second part however I could not find any information on how can I effectively address the form fields in XBAP. I only have access to the hosted application with no access to source code. The developer tools show no information for the XBAP form fields as this is encapsulated in a secured framework(XAML/WPF). Please help or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe this will give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22821902/4996248 This is about JavaScript and XBAP, but JavaScript code which interacts with the browser in some way can usually be translated to VBScript which in turn can be tweaked to VBA.

Comment: Thank you @JohnColeman. I have no experience with jscript. can you help with more details please.